# How to decrement value on a MIFARE Classic value block using PN532 reader?

Tags: rfid, mifare, lib-nfc

I'm trying to manage value block with a Mifare Classic and PN532 reader.
I'm using an open source library named "libnfc" but I do not see anything related to value blocks in this library.

Does anyone know how I could make increment, decrement and transfer calls with this reader & library?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the header [`utils/mifare.h`](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/mifare.h) (and its associated implementation [`utils/mifare.c`](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/mifare.c)). They contain an implementation of the MIFARE reader commands. For instance, for the increment command, you would use something like:

```
mp.mpv.abtValue[0] = 1;
mp.mpv.abtValue[1] = 0;
mp.mpv.abtValue[2] = 0;
mp.mpv.abtValue[3] = 0;

nfc_initiator_mifare_cmd(pnd, MC_INCREMENT, blockNumber, &mp);
```

Where `pnd` is a `nfc_device *`, `mp` is a `mifare_param` and you previously authenticated to that sector (see [`utils/nfc-mfclassic.c`](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/nfc-mfclassic.c)).

Comment: Thanks Michael! but I'm using a Python wrapper of the library (nfcpy library) and seems not to have avalilable the modules in the "utils" folder.

Comment: I'm looking for a nfc library in Python but is difficult to find one with decrement and increment functions. I'm reading a little about how to use libraries written in C if my program is written in Python, but I prefer reuse some library ready to use, of course ;)

Comment: @crossmax You should have explained that in your question. Note that [nfcpy](https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy) (or formerly [available here](https://launchpad.net/nfcpy)) is certainly **not** a wrapper for libnfc. nfcpy is a completely independent implementation. Hence asking for libnfc if you want nfcpy does not make sense at all.

Comment: Btw. nfcpy does not implement *any* commands related to MIFARE Classic (not even authentication and block-oriented memory access). And according to this [bug report](https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy/issues/32) nfcpy won't include any support for MIFARE Classic in future versions.

Comment: I was testing several libraries and mistook nfcpy with pynfc. With [`pynfc`](https://github.com/ikelos/pynfc) I can do increment, decrement and restore a value block. Thank you for taking your time